# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 Assets library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Assets Library in not accessible in my Sharepoint Foundation 2013.
What must I do to activate it ?

Thank you (and sorry for my poor English)

Comment: What is the site template?

Answer (score 0):

Asset Library is avaiable in the SharePoint Foundation 2013, You can add it following the below steps.

1. Browse to the site where you want to create the library.
2. In the Quick Launch, click **Site Contents**.
3. Under Lists, Libraries, and other Apps, click **Add an app.**
4. **NOTE**    To create an Asset Library, you must have permission to
   create lists. If you don't have sufficient permissions, you won't
   see the **Add an app** link.
5. Under **Apps you can add**, click **Asset Library**.
6. In the Adding Asset Library dialog box, type a name for the library,
   and then click **Create**.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-an-Asset-Library-to-store-image-audio-or-video-files-96532bf6-dc72-4f82-bf0a-21ef945c4d04?CorrelationId=1452d2e0-f81f-4545-9f32-10ee20f4bd69&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Hello, I have the permissions, I can see Add an app, but Asset Library is not present. Thank you